# New to git--just need to sync one file

Tags: eclipse, git, github, synchronization, git-pull

I managed to finally get EGit in Eclipse to work (still don't know how) and I've committed/pushed [my current project](https://github.com/SturmB/Scheduling) up to GitHub. So far, so good. Looking at it on GitHub's site, I see it wants me to make a README.md file to provide a nice description. Fine, I think, I'll just use the tool it's providing me with to get it started, then have it sync back down to my local computer where I can further modify it and keep it synced.

So I created a quick README.md file on GitHub's site. But now, when I perform a "Pull" action in Eclipse, I am told that there's nothing new to pull, or something like that. Why is it not getting the new file that was created on GitHub's site, and how can I get it so that I can make changes to it whenever I want?

Comment: How did you create this file on their site? And what is the **exact** error message?

Comment: I had since lost that error message when I tried to configure a Fetch in Eclipse's Git Repositories panel -> Remotes -> origin. I then got a new error message when attempting a Pull, which I describe below in my comment to the answer.

As for how the file was created originally: When looking at my project on GitHub, there was a message stating something like "We recommend you create a README.md file to explain your project to visitors" along with a big, green button to create one automatically. I clicked that button; that's how the file was created directly on their site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have git installed you can use a terminal and type in the root of your repository:

```
git pull origin master
```

or you could try checking out only that file:

```
git checkout README.md
```

Comment: That first bit was what I needed. I had since tried just deleting the "Push" and "Fetch" configurations under Remotes -> origin in the Git Repositories panel. But then, when I attempted to re-create a Push config, I was getting the "rejected - non-fast forward" error message. Your first line (plus some [help at GitHub's site](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-non-fast-forward-errors/) was what I needed to correct it. Strange that a simple "Pull" using Eclipse's UI didn't work, but the CLI version does.

Comment: I'm happy to hear that you found a solution, perhaps the pull configuration was not correctly configured. I find that using the command line is always better as you have more control but sometimes it is easier if the IDE does everything so you can focus more on developing than configuring.